# Get values from string .net c# with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to parse string:

```
????log L 07/31/2012 - 14:32:50: "Username1<4><STEAM_ID_PENDING><CT>" killed "Username2<2><STEAM_ID_PENDING><TERRORIST>" with "m4a1"
```

I must get values:

1. Username1
2. Username2
3. m4a1

I have regex pattern

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[^\"]+\"([^<]+)<[^\"]+\" killed \"([A-Za-z0-9]+)[^\"]+\" with \"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\"");
```

This works perfectly if second username does not contains `_` this or this `-`
If first contains regex getting value.

Please help me to modify my pattern

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[^\"]+\"([^<]+)<[^\"]+\" killed \"([^<]+)[^\"]+\" with \"([A-Za-z0-9]+)\"")
```

Group for finding name was:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

I replaced it with:

```
([^<]+)
```

which is a pattern used to find first username.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(?<Username1>"Username1(?<data>[^"]*)")\s+killed\s+(?<Username1>"Username2(?<data>[^"]*)")\s+with\s+(?<m4a1>"m4a1(?<data>[^"]*)")
```

Named groups will return their respective values.